# In perl how can i subtract 10 days from a date which is passed through a text file and output in dd-Month-YYYY(01-jan-1990)

Tags: perl, datetime

In perl is there a way to subtract 10 days from a date which will be passed from a text file and the output should be in 01-jan-1999 format .

i am using the below code for reading the file and getting the date after that i am strucked with subtracting the date.

### date.txt

25-jan-2013

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use DateTime;

my $inp= "date.txt";
my $todate;
my $fromdate;

open(date,"$inp");
while(<date>)
{
$todate = $_ ;
print "$todate \n";
}

$fromdate = $todate - 10 days ;
```

Comment: The solution you need is in these two answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486470/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-datetime-object-in-perl and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403395/subtracting-two-dates-with-perl-datetime

Answer (score 10):

Here's an answer that uses DateTime.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime;

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
  pattern => '%d-%B-%Y'
);

my $input = '25-jan-2013';

my $todate = $parser->parse_datetime($input);

my $fromdate = $todate->clone;
$fromdate->subtract(days => 10);
say 'From: ', $fromdate->strftime('%d-%B-%Y');
say 'To: ', $todate->strftime('%d-%B-%Y');
```

Answer (score 3):

In the old days, you would use [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) to convert your time into the number of seconds since the Epoc, subtract the number of seconds in ten days (10 * 24 * 60 * 60), and then convert it back into a time using [localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html). It was fun, it was educational, and mostly, it was overly complex and prone to error.

When I'm able to use Perl 5.10 or above, I prefer to use [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) because it makes things simple, and most importantly, it's a standard Perl module. Plus, it plays well with [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html), another standard Perl module:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $date = "25-jan-2013";

#Create the "date object". The `%d-%b-%Y" is format the date is in
my $my_date = Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%d-%b-%Y");  #

#Now subtract ten days from it
$my_date -= ( 10 * ONE_DAY );  #Constant from Time::Seconds

say $my_date;   #Prints out Tue Jan 15 00:00:00 2013

#Printing it out in dd-mmm-yyyy format you had
say $my_date->mday . "-" . $my_date->monname . "-" . $my_date->year;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Date::Manip](http://p3rl.org/Date%3a%3aManip):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Date::Manip;

my $todate  = '25-jan-2013';
my $newdate = DateCalc(ParseDate($todate), ParseDateDelta('- 10 days'));

print "$newdate\n";
```

Comment: If someone is already using DateTime, you really don't want to recommend that they switch back to Date::Manip :/

Comment: @DaveCross - How did the OP *use* DateTime, other than bring it in as a Module?  The OP didn't state that DateTime *must* be used.  "...switch back to Date::Manip"  The OP didn't state that Date::Manip was tried. The recommendation here is perfectly appropriate (+1) as a means towards the OP's end--which wasn't obtain by using DateTime.

Comment: Well, loading the DateTime module is a better start than doing anything with Date::Manip :-) And I didn't mean "switch back" as "do back to something you've previously tried". I meant "take your Perl programming style back to the mid-1990s". In DateTime.pm Perl has a flexible and powerful date and time handling framework. Using anything else is pointless.